# Swi prolog on windows cant take filepaths

Tags: windows, prolog, swi-prolog

Hi im trying to compile a .pl file using swi prolog (on a windows machine).

Now i can understand that this first i am supposed to give the file like this:

```
['Users\Ask\Documents\Prolog\firstpro.pl']
```

And then compile

```
.
```

But when i do this i get this error:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Undefined character escape in quoted atom or string: `\A'
ERROR: ['Users
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: \Ask\Documents\Prolog\firstpro.pl']
```

It seems like swi interprets my forwardslash with a escape sequence, and therefore stops.
But how else should I find my file?

thanks a lot

Comment: That's actually a backward slash and is interpreted as an escape character. Try using `/` instead?

Comment: nice, this actually works when i also inculde C:/ thanks

Answer (score 0):

The character `\`inside an atom is used for escape sequences (as the error message hints). Thus, to represent a backslash, you need to write two bsckslashes. Write instead:

```
['Users\\Ask\\Documents\\Prolog\\firstpro.pl']
```

That said, you can use forward slashes for paths with SWI-Prolog running on Windows. But note that the permissible representation of paths on Windows systems depend on the Prolog compiler.

Comment: the same thing happens when i use two backslashes

Comment: @s3j80 Same error? Can you updated your question with the query using two backslashes?